# Tough Chicken Skin

Tags: chicken, grilling, roasting

Just roasted a chicken, olive oiled the skin, applied chicken rub and placed the chicken in a preheated 350 degree grill. It came to temperature in about two hours. Skin was very tough! What does it take to get a tender tasty chicken?

Comment: Was this in an outdoor grill? Propane? Charcoal?

Comment: Traeger pellet grill

Comment: 2 hours at 350 seems like a lot unless it was a really big chicken. What internal temperature was it when you took it out?

Comment: You say the skin was very tough, but then you ask what it takes to get a tender, tasty chicken. Was it the skin that was tough or the flesh of the chicken? Were there problems with the flavor?

Comment: Have you tried separating the skin from the chicken (run your fingers through the skin and chicken; not so much that you take it off however)

Answer (score 2):

If you want crispy chicken skin, you need to begin with dry chicken and a hot oven.  When I roast a chicken, I [spatchcock](https://www.marthastewart.com/891288/how-spatchcock-chicken) first.  Then salt liberally, and place in the refrigerator, uncovered, for at least 24 hours, and up to 48 hours.  This removes moisture from the skin.  I roast at a high temperature: 450F (232C) for about an hour and 10 minutes, but check the temperature in the thigh for best results.

I suspect that the low heat, wet and oiled skin, and likely overcooking caused your skin and chicken to be tough.